# Order members of OSM multipolygon relations

Tags: openstreetmap, relates

Im writing an importer for OSM files. Now i'm importing the relations with multipolygoins.

The documentation says

```
The order of the relation members does not matter (but properly sorted member lists can help human editors to verify completeness).
```

Is there a pre defined algorithm to find the ways which form one closed polygon? Preferably in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/) is written in Java and it is able to order members of various relations very well.

Comment: OpenJUMP is using JOSM library for converting OSM features into GIS style JTS features. OSM plugin comes with recent OpenJUMP 1.7 Plus version and it may give some inspiration. The source code is in http://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/code/HEAD/tree/plug-ins/OsmFileReaderPlugin/